# macOS (10.13 High Sierra) no longer stores screensaver settings in com.apple.screensaver

Tags: macos, security, screensaver, macos-high-sierra

So far my project had been relying on the following commands in order to tweak screensaver settings:

```
defaults write com.apple.screensaver askForPasswordDelay 0
defaults write com.apple.screensaver askForPassword true
```

As of macOS High Sierra (10.13) it seems like these settings are no longer stored in com.apple.screensaver

I'd like to avoid Apple Script to achieve such thing, any suggestions?

Comment: This question is off topic here, you should post it on Ask Different - the Stack Overflow Apple forum

Answer (score 3):

Victor Vrantchan explains this in a great blog post here:

https://blog.kolide.com/screensaver-security-on-macos-10-13-is-broken-a385726e2ae2

In summary you cant query but you can mange.:

> Until Apple resolves this bug, screensaver security/lock settings must be managed carefully. More specifically:
>
> - Enforce the profile ASAP, during initial bootstrap.
> - Make sure the askForPasswordDelay key is used in the profile.

Answer (score 1):

Using `defaults write` no longer works as of 10.13.

http://www.openradar.me/35462422

You can use this gist to accomplish it using profiles instead: 
https://gist.github.com/mcw0933/21b8a9e292e83c69931f5de0d2ae1883

Comment: Thanks for sharing! If I use the profile as-is (only replacing my username) I always get askForPasswordDelay set to "immediately", even though the default value seems to be 5 (seconds?) and no matter what other int value I set it to. How can I actually set a time, e.g. 5 seconds? On macOS 10.14.6

Comment: Ah so this only happens if I install via install.sh, profile installs under "User Profiles", whereas opening `askforpassworddelay.mobileconfig` directly makes it work as expected, and gets installed under "Device Profiles". `sudo install.sh` however installs it correctly :) So problem solved.

Comment: Oh, nice!  Yes - you do want it installed under Device Profiles.  I can't explain why the script in my gist does so for me, but not for you.  Glad to know `sudo` worked for you.